# got this error after created electron application and try to open

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'windowData.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:447:3)
    at Object.func (electron/js2c/asar.js:140:31)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140:31)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:349:35)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542:40)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:542:40)
    at App.createWindow (/opt/webtodesktop/resources/app.asar/main.js:12:21)
    at App.emit (events.js:208:15)
```

i have generated an electron application for linux .when I try to open my application after installation it gets above error .

main.js file uses windowData.json file to read window options (height,width,url).

Comment: Where is `windowData.json` located? how are you opening and requiring it (sounds like you're reading it)? once the application is built, the lookup path used by the electron main thread is different from environment to environment, I suggest you to add further logs (like the calculated filepath and so on) or, even better, to include such json at compile-time in order to avoid the fopen at runtime. If you plan to save such json, save it in the application data folder (which again, changes for every targeted platform).

Comment: windowData.json file is placed just below main.js. 
reading json like this main.js 

var contents = fs.readFileSync("windowData.json", "utf-8");
  var jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents); 
window.loadURL(jsnContent.url);

Comment: `readFileSync` is not path-aware, hence it will open the file where the application is installed. You should use either `app.getPath('userData')` or `app.getPath('appData')` depending where the json is stored after installation.

Comment: I could able to preview the electron window with an electron $npm run electron. but I could not able to preview after I have installed app in Linux and try to open